# Check if path in json object exists?

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I am currently doing something like this to access an array in my json object

```
teacher_topical_array = teacher_obj["medication"]["topical"]
```

However before doing that I would like to make sure the path `teacher_obj["medication"]["topical"]` exists and I am looking for a simpler approach to accomplish this.

Now I understand I could do something like this

```
if "medication" in teacher_obj:
    if "topical" in teacher_obj["medication"]:
             #yes the key exists
```

I wanted to know if I could accomplish the above in a different way. That might be more effective if I had to check for something like

```
teacher_obj["medication"]["topical"]["anotherkey"]["someOtherKey"]
```

Comment: You can use exception handling `try: teacher_obj["medication"]["topical"]["anotherkey"]["someOtherKey"] except KeyError: ...`.

Comment: @SnakesandCoffee Woah. The linked dupe has a similar answer to mine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The LYBL approach: Chain `get` calls, if you don't want to use `try-except` braces...

```
teacher_topical_array = teacher_obj.get("medication", {}).get("topical", None)
```

---

The [EAFP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11360858/what-is-the-eafp-principle-in-python) approach: Use a `try`-`except` block and catch a `KeyError`.

```
try:
    teacher_topical_array = teacher_obj["medication"]["topical"]
except KeyError:
    teacher_topical_array = []
```

Comment: I like the LYBL approach will go with that